# Change colour of phase diagrams in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting the following phase diagram and am facing a lot of difficulties changing the colour of the lines in the graphic:

```
f[α_, σ_]:= "some expression"
g[α_, σ_]:= "some expression"

ContourPlot[{f[α_, σ_] == 0, g[α_, σ_] == 0}, {α, 0, 1}, {σ, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"p=1/2" "p=9/10"}, 
  FrameLabel -> 
    {Style["Off Diagonal Variance α", Bold, 16], 
     Style["Diagonal Standard Deviation σ", Bold, 16]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, 14]]
```

[image]

I would like to change the colours of the lines displayed but `ContourPlot` doesn't seem to have the options to change these particular contours. I would like to have mores sober colours.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `ContourStyle->{Red, Blue}`?

Comment: ... so it was that easy... It works! thanks.